# Avoiding nested if statements with numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I'm attempting to convert coordinate systems and then evaluate which coordinates are defined in a GUI. This function will later be built out for that. Currently, I'm attempting to avoid nested if statements.

Essentially, would like to evaluate if the np.array is empty or not. Then evaluate the variable, with those points, to check if they are empty. If they are empty, then evaluate the statements within. I'm trying to avoid more nested if statements, as well as an unnecessary amount of shared data between variables, if possible. Any suggestions?

I've tried building multiple variables and then comparing those. Although this isn't necessarily what I would like either.

```
#!/bin/python3
import numpy as np
import math as m
import os
import sys
import ctypes

def cart2sp(x, y, z):
    """Converts data from cartesian coordinates into spherical.

    Args:
        x (scalar or array_like): X-component of data.
        y (scalar or array_like): Y-component of data.
        z (scalar or array_like): Z-component of data.

    Returns:
        Tuple (r, theta, phi) of data in spherical coordinates.
    """
    x = np.asarray(x)
    y = np.asarray(y)
    z = np.asarray(z)
    scalar_input = False
    if x.ndim == 0 and y.ndim == 0 and z.ndim == 0:
        x = x[None]
        y = y[None]
        z = z[None]
        scalar_input = True
    r = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)
    theta = np.arcsin(z/r)
    phi = np.arctan2(y, x)
    if scalar_input:
        return (r.squeeze(), theta.squeeze(), phi.squeeze())
    return (r, theta, phi)

def sp2cart(r, theta, phi):
    """Converts data in spherical coordinates into cartesian.

    Args:
        r (scalar or array_like): R-component of data.
        theta (scalar or array_like): Theta-component of data.
        phi (scalar or array_like): Phi-component of data.

    Returns:
        Tuple (x, y, z) of data in cartesian coordinates.
    """
    r = np.asarray(r)
    theta = np.asarray(theta)
    phi = np.asarray(phi)
    scalar_input = False
    if r.ndim == 0 and theta.ndim == 0 and phi.ndim == 0:
        r = r[None]
        theta = theta[None]
        phi = phi[None]
        scalar_input = True
    x = r*np.cos(theta)*np.cos(phi)
    y = r*np.cos(theta)*np.sin(phi)
    z = r*np.sin(theta)
    if scalar_input:
        return (x.squeeze(), y.squeeze(), z.squeeze())
    return (x, y, z)

def cart2cyl(x, y, z):
    """Converts data in cartesian coordinates into cylyndrical.

    Args:
        x (scalar or array_like): X-component of data.
        y (scalar or array_like): Y-component of data.
        z (scalar or array_like): Z-component of data.

    Returns:
        Tuple (r, phi, z) of data in cylindrical coordinates.
    """
    x = np.asarray(x)
    y = np.asarray(y)
    z = np.asarray(z)
    scalar_input = False
    if x.ndim == 0 and y.ndim == 0 and z.ndim == 0:
        x = x[None]
        y = y[None]
        z = z[None]
        scalar_input = True
    r = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
    phi = np.arctan2(y, x)
    if scalar_input:
        return (r.squeeze(), phi.squeeze(), z.squeeze())
    return (r, phi, z)

def cyl2cart(r, phi, z):
    """Converts data in cylindrical coordinates into cartesian.

    Args:
        r (scalar or array_like): R-component of data.
        phi (scalar or array_like): Phi-component of data.
        z (scalar or array_like): Z-component of data.

    Returns:
        Tuple (x, y, z) of data in cartesian coordinates.
    """
    r = np.asarray(r)
    phi = np.asarray(phi)
    z = np.asarray(z)
    scalar_input = False
    if r.ndim == 0 and phi.ndim == 0 and z.ndim == 0:
        r = r[None]
        phi = phi[None]
        z = z[None]
        scalar_input = True
    x = r*np.cos(phi)
    y = r*np.sin(phi)
    if scalar_input:
        return (x.squeeze(), y.squeeze(), z.squeeze())
    return (x, y, z)

def mx_rot_x(gamma):
    """Returns rotational matrix for right-handed rotation
    around X axis.

    Args:
        gamma (scalar): Rotation angle around X in radians.

    Returns:
        Numpy rotational matrix.
    """
    return np.matrix([
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, np.cos(gamma), -np.sin(gamma)],
        [0, np.sin(gamma), np.cos(gamma)]
    ])

def mx_rot_y(theta):
    """Returns rotational matrix for right-handed rotation
    around Y axis.

    Args:
        theta (scalar): Rotation angle around Y in radians.

    Returns:
        Numpy rotational matrix.
    """
    return np.matrix([
        [np.cos(theta), 0, np.sin(theta)],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [-np.sin(theta), 0, np.cos(theta)]
    ])

def mx_rot_z(phi):
    """Returns rotational matrix for right-handed rotation
    around Z axis.

    Args:
        phi (scalar): Rotation angle around Z in radians.

    Returns:
        Numpy rotational matrix.
    """
    return np.matrix([
        [np.cos(phi), -np.sin(phi), 0],
        [np.sin(phi), np.cos(phi), 0],
        [0, 0, 1]
    ])

def mx_rot(theta, phi, gamma):
    """Returns rotational matrix for compound rotation
    around X, Y and Z axes. The order of rotation is X-Y-Z.

    Args:
        theta (scalar): Rotation angle around Y in radians.
        phi (scalar): Rotational angle around in Z radians.
        gamma (scalar): Rotational angle around X in radians.

    Returns:
        Numpy rotational matrix.
    """
    return np.dot(
        mx_rot_z(phi),
        np.dot(mx_rot_y(theta), mx_rot_x(gamma))
    )

def mx_rot_reverse(theta, phi, gamma):
    """Returns rotational matrix for compound rotations
    around X, Y and Z axes. The order of rotation is Z-Y-X.

    Args:
        theta (scalar): Rotational angle around Y in radians.
        phi (scalar): Rotational angle around in Z radians.
        gamma (scalar): Rotational angle around X in radians.

    Returns:
        Numpy rotational matrix.
    """
    return np.dot(
        mx_rot_x(gamma),
        np.dot(mx_rot_y(theta), mx_rot_z(phi))
    )

def mx_apply(T, x, y, z):
    """Applies rotation to data using rotational matrix.

    Args:
        T (numpy.matrix): Rotational matrix.
        x (scalar or array_like): X-component of data.
        y (scalar or array_like): Y-component of data.
        z (scalar or array_like): Z-component of data.

    Returns:
        Tuple (x, y, z) of data in cartesian coordinates.
    """
    x = np.asarray(x)
    y = np.asarray(y)
    z = np.asarray(z)
    scalar_input = False
    if x.ndim == 0 and y.ndim == 0 and z.ndim == 0:
        x = x[None]
        y = y[None]
        z = z[None]
        scalar_input = True
    x_ = T[0, 0]*x+T[0, 1]*y+T[0, 2]*z
    y_ = T[1, 0]*x+T[1, 1]*y+T[1, 2]*z
    z_ = T[2, 0]*x+T[2, 1]*y+T[2, 2]*z
    if scalar_input:
        return (x_.squeeze(), y_.squeeze(), z_.squeeze())
    return (x_, y_, z_)

def cxform(cs_from, cs_to, dt, x, y, z):
    """Performs conversion between various geocentric and heliocentric
    coordinate systems.

    Args:
        cs_from (str): Indentifier of the source coordinate system.
            Can be one of 'GEI', 'J2000', 'GEO', 'MAG', 'GSE', 'GSM',
            'SM', 'RTN', 'GSEQ', 'HEE', 'HAE', 'HEEQ'.
        cs_to: Identifier of target coordinate system. Can be one of
            'GEI', 'J2000', 'GEO', 'MAG', 'GSE', 'GSM', 'SM', 'RTN',
            'GSEQ', 'HEE', 'HAE', 'HEEQ'.
        dt (datetime or array_like of datetime): Datetime of the
            conversion.
        x (scalar or array_like): X-component of data.
        y (scalar or array_like): Y-component of data.
        z (scalar or array_like): Z-component of data.

    Returns:
        Tuple (x, y, z) of data in target coordinate system.
    """
    if sys.platform == 'wind32' or sys.platform == 'cygwin':
        libcxform_path = os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(__file__), 'cxform-c.dll'
        )
    else:
        libcxform_path = os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(__file__), 'cxform-c.so'
        )
    libcxform = ctypes.CDLL(libcxform_path)
    dt = np.asarray(dt)
    x_from = np.asarray(x)
    y_from = np.asarray(y)
    z_from = np.asarray(z)
    if not dt.shape == x_from.shape == y_from.shape == z_from.shape:
        raise ValueError(
            "x, y, z and dt should be scalars or vectors of the same size"
        )
    scalar_input = False
    if dt.ndim == 0:
        dt = dt[None]
        x_from = x_from[None]
        y_from = y_from[None]
        z_from = z_from[None]
        scalar_input = True
    x_to = np.empty(x_from.shape)
    y_to = np.empty(y_from.shape)
    z_to = np.empty(z_from.shape)
    for i in range(dt.size):
        es = libcxform.date2es(
            ctypes.c_int(dt.flat[i].year),
            ctypes.c_int(dt.flat[i].month),
            ctypes.c_int(dt.flat[i].day),
            ctypes.c_int(dt.flat[i].hour),
            ctypes.c_int(dt.flat[i].minute),
            ctypes.c_int(dt.flat[i].second)
        )
        v_in = np.array(
            [x_from.flat[i], y_from.flat[i], z_from.flat[i]],
            dtype=np.float_
        )
        v_out = np.empty(3, dtype=np.float_)
        libcxform.cxform(
            str.encode(cs_from),
            str.encode(cs_to),
            ctypes.c_double(es),
            v_in.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)),
            v_out.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
        )
        x_to.flat[i] = v_out[0]
        y_to.flat[i] = v_out[1]
        z_to.flat[i] = v_out[2]
    if scalar_input:
        return (x_to.squeeze(), y_to.squeeze(), z_to.squeeze())
    return (x_to, y_to, z_to)



# Functions
def cart_2_cyl(pts):
    #Conversion - Start Cartesian (Cartesian to Cylindrical)
    pts[1,0], pts[1,1], pts[1,2] = cart2cyl(pts[0,0],pts[0,1],pts[0,2])
    #Read
    pos_cartcyl_cart = pts[1,0], pts[1,1], pts[1,2]
    return(pos_cartcyl_cart)

def cart_2_sph(pts):

    #Conversion - Start Spherical(Cartesian to Spherical)
    pts[2,0], pts[2,1] , pts[2,2] = cart2sp(pts[0,0], pts[0,1], pts[0,2])
    #Read
    pos_cartsph_cart = pts[2,0], pts[2,1], pts[2,2]   
    return(pos_cartsph_cart)


def sph_2_cart(pts):
    #Conversion - Start Spherical(Spherical to Cartesian)
    pts[0,0], pts[0,1], pts[0,2] = sp2cart(pts[2,0], pts[2,1], pts[2,2])
    #Read
    pos_sp2cart_sph = pts[0,0], pts[0,1], pts[0,2]
    return(pos_sp2cart_sph)

def cyl_2_cart(pts):
    #Conversion - Start Cylindrical (Cylindrical to Cartesian)
    pts[0,0], pts[0,1], pts[0,2] = cyl2cart(pts[1,0], pts[1,1], pts[1,2])
    #Read
    pos_cylcart_cyl = pts[0,0], pts[0,1], pts[0,2]
    return(pos_cylcart_cyl)

ThreeThree = (3,3)

pts = np.empty(ThreeThree)
pts = np.empty(ThreeThree)
pts = np.empty(ThreeThree)

cart = np.empty((1,3))
cyl = np.empty((1,3))
sph = np.empty((1,3))

# pts[2,0], pts[2,1], pts[2,2] = 1, 1, 1
# cart =  np.array((pts[2,0], pts[2,1], pts[2,2]))

pts[1,0], pts[1,1], pts[1,2] = 1, 1, 1
cyl =  np.array((pts[1,0], pts[1,1], pts[1,2]))

# pts[2,0], pts[2,1], pts[2,2] = 1, 1, 1
# sph =  np.array((pts[2,0], pts[2,1], pts[2,2]))


## MAIN LOGIC ##

if not pts.size == 0:
    # Check Cartesian
    if cart.size == 0:  #If cart array is empty -> Return True
        print("\nCartesian:", cart)
        if not cyl.any():
            print("Cylindrical Coordinates are Empty")
        else:

            print("Cylindrical:", cart_2_cyl(pts))

        if not sph.any():
            print("Spherical Coordinates are Empty")
        else:
            print("Spherical:", cart_2_sph(pts),'\n') 

    if not cyl.size == 0:
        print("\nCylindrical:", cyl)
        # Check Spherical
        if not sph.any():  #If sph array is empty -> Return True
            print("Spherical Coordinates are Empty")
        else:   
            cyl_2_cart(pts)
            print("Spherical:", cart_2_sph(pts))
        if not cart.any():
            print("\nCartesian Coordinates are Empty")
        else:
            print("Cartesian:", cyl_2_cart(pts),'\n')

    if sph.size == 0:
        print("\n Spherical:", sph)
        # Check Spherical
        if not cyl.any():  #If sph array is empty -> Return True
            print("Cylindrical Coordinates are Empty")
        else:   
            sph_2_cart(pts)
            print("Cylindrical:", cart_2_cyl(pts))
        if not cart.any():
            print("\nCartesian Coordinates are Empty")
        else:
            print("Cartesian:", cyl_2_cart(pts),'\n')

else:   
    print('Unsuccessful')
```

I'm expecting only one if (cart, cyl, sph).size == 0 to be evaluated, given the variable being set.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Any chance of making a *minimal* [mcve] that duplicates the problem without the `from ai import cs` import?

Comment: These two statements look mutually exclusive - `if not cart.size == 0:
    # Check Cartesian
    if cart.size == 0:` - did you get that right?

Comment: Yes, artifact of debugging. If not cart.size == 0: should say if if not pts.size == 0: -> edited.

Comment: I can do that, for sure!

Comment: Are those `cyl_2_cart(pts)` with no assignment doing anything meaningful? Also, should `print("Cylindrical:", cart_2_sph(pts))` be `print("Cylindrical:", cart_2_cyl(pts))`?

Comment: Yes, they rewrite the pts array. Correct, I've mainly been debugging the second nested if.

Comment: Do they really rewrite an array? It seems like they just create a new array, which is then discarded (the result not assigned to any variable)

Comment: When I remove the return from those functions, the output is None to my prints.  I believe they are, once called.